# Backward caller with abstract classes

Tags: php

As relatively new with abstract classes, I was wondering if I can do something like this:

```
abstract class A
{
  public function save() { echo "A"; $this->_save();}
}

class B extends A
{
  public function _save { echo "b";}
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->save();
```

Tests was not success, so is there someone with better explanation or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the function `_save` as abstract method of class A, something like:

```
abstract class A
{
  public function save() { echo "A"; $this->_save();}

  public abstract function _save();
}
```

For more details read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: Still empty result. Could it be because of the PHP version? I`m currently with 5.6 - I guess it should do the work.

Comment: There are missing braces for _save.

Comment: Dammit. I always promise to myself never to code before drink my second coffee. Just missed the braces. Thank you very much!! You`re ma man!!!